# App made with android studio shows ads only on one mobile phones but not on other phones

Tags: android

I am having problems with an android studio source code.
There is an asus mobile phone in which ads are coming but in other phones ads are not coming .... Can you tell me whats the reason please ??.I m having asus zenfone max pro m1( nougat android ) on which admob ads are showing but not showing on other phones like vivo v3 ( lollipop android version ??). I also tested the app with other phones having nougat but same problem exists. Please tell me the possible reasons of this problem .

Comment: provide some code 
where and how did you add ads to your project

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.androiud.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.5"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: // slider library
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'

    // Google Libraries
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'

    // Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'

Comment: please add the code to the answer using edit button
and please add the code for calling and setting the adView
it might be good to see your manifest and gradle but it is important to see how you use the adView and how you create `AdRequest`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash">

    <!-- Required Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Change package name in below 2 lines of Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.droidoxy.easymoneyrewards.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.app.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.AppActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppLTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Registering Additional Activities -->
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.VideosActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.RecoveryActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.RedeemActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.InstructionsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.EarningHistoryActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.RedeemHistoryActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.AboutActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.ReferActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.ErrorActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppLTheme" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.LoginActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.SignupActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.IntroActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />


        <!-- The Finest Artist Activities -->
        <activity android:name="com.thefinestartist.ytpa.YouTubePlayerActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:screenOrientation="sensor" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.thefinestartist.ytpa.YouTubePlayerActivity.ApiKey" android:value="AIzaSyAOfxiG4aV66h3XmssCEkP3qCvCqMbDGDI" />


        <!-- StartApp Components -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.ads.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.OverlayActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.FullScreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <service android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.PeriodicMetaDataService" />
        <service android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.InfoEventService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.BootCompleteListener" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- End of StartApp activities integration -->

        <!-- Component that firebase needs -->
        <service android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.cashbuddy.paytmcash.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- the libraries that google play service configuration need to use -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="[ADMOB_APP_ID]"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```